# Delete all columns not in list

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete all the columns in a file ***except*** the ones in my defined list. The sub below does the opposite.

While workable, I'd rather not define what I want to delete as I have no control over what column names are added in the source file and I will keep having to update the list.

I need to keep ~90 columns, so I don't want to define them as a string within the sub.

PACEKEEP is the list of column names I want to keep
contour-export is the source file.

I'd like to keep the list PACEKEEP in a file separate from the working file (call PACEKEEP from a static file). Currently I add PACEKEEP as a sheet on contour-export.

```vb
Sub PACEKILL()
Dim f As Range, c As Range
For Each c In Sheets("PACEKEEP").Range("A2", Sheets("PACEKEEP").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set f = Sheets("contour-export").Rows(1).Find(c.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then f.EntireColumn.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

The sub will delete the column headers in the file. I want to delete the columns not in the file.

Comment: Flip the logic: loop through the first row and look up the values against the PACEKEEP list.

Answer (score 0):

You ask several questions, but here's how to open another file:

```
Sub OpenAnotherFile()
Dim wbM As Workbook
Dim sUrl As String, b As Boolean
Dim app As New Excel.Application
app.Visible = False
sUrl = "C:\Temp\myFile.xlsx"
sName = Mid(sDir, InStrRev(sUrl, "\") + 1)
b = isFileOpen(sName)
If b Then
    Set wbM = Application.Workbooks.Item(sName)
    If wbM.readOnly Then
        MsgBox "File is read only", vbExclamation, "Read only"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    Set wbM = app.Workbooks.Add(sUrl)
End If

'Do stuff

wbM.SaveAs Filename:=sUrl
wbM.Close
app.Quit
Set app = Nothing
End Sub

Function isFileOpen(sName As String) As Boolean
Dim wb As Workbook
isMasterOpen = False
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name = sName Then
        isMasterOpen = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb
End Function
```

How to look for empty rows, look here: [How to find out if an entire row is blank in excel thorough vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628057/how-to-find-out-if-an-entire-row-is-blank-in-excel-thorough-vba)

Comment: Thanks for the script, I will see how it works on my side as soon as i have access back to the dbs needed.  Someone did an access purge last night and I am DOA for a few days

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Bad Columns

```vb
Sub PACEKILL()
  
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("PACEKEEP")
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = sws.Range("A2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Contour-Export")
    Dim drg As Range:
    Set drg = dws.Range("A1", dws.Cells(1, dws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    
    Dim scIndexes(): scIndexes = Application.Match(drg, srg, 0)
    
    Dim drgDel As Range, c As Long, IsBadColumnFound As Boolean
    
    For c = 1 To UBound(scIndexes)
        If IsError(scIndexes(c)) Then
            If IsBadColumnFound Then
                Set drgDel = Union(drgDel, drg.Cells(c))
            Else
                Set drgDel = drg.Cells(c)
                IsBadColumnFound = True
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    
    If IsBadColumnFound Then
        drgDel.EntireColumn.Delete
        MsgBox "Bad columns deleted.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No bad columns found.", vbExclamation
    End If
 
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the script, I will try to implement this soon to see how it runs on my side.  Someone thought it would be a good idea to kill my access to the db in question last night, so i wont be able to validate for a few days.